# How to print file to Shiny using renderText

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm missing something here because the image doesn't display.

Thanks.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  src = "einstein.jpg"
  print(file.exists(src))
  out = '<img src="einstein.jpg" style=width:304px;height:228px;>'
  output$text3<-renderText(out)

  })

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  htmlOutput("text3")

))
```

Comment: are you trying to display the jpg or the code associated with the html tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you put your picture `einstein.jpg` in a `img/` subfolder of your app, you can use `addResourcePath` to allow access to it:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui=fluidPage(htmlOutput("text3")),
         server=(function(input, output) {
           addResourcePath("foo", "img")  
           out = '<img src="/foo/einstein.jpg" style=width:304px;height:228px;>'
           output$text3<-renderText(out)
         }))
```