# R opening a tif image, path does not work when running through web browser

Tags: r, shiny

I have an issue about opening a tif image.
If I run the program in R-Studio everything is ok and I can open a tif image which the path is for example :

```
D:/SCAN/C01/D0002/ident/BPE27000.TIF
```

But if I run the program through Firefox, it is not able to open it.

Would you know why ?

I don't think my question is a duplicate because I have something like 350 000 TIF images and I can't copy them in an app subfolder. I have copied them on drive D for my application tests, but they will be on a network drive at last.

So how can specify a valid network path through the web browser ?

Thank you very much.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print file to Shiny using renderText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008543/how-to-print-file-to-shiny-using-rendertext)

Comment: [Most web browsers don't support tiff files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser)

Comment: Ok, I take note. Thank you very much MrFlick.