# R shiny , renderImage / renderUI. How to deal with directories and system commands?

Tags: r, shiny

I have trouble to implement a renderImage in a ShinyApp. At some point, I launch a function which generates 3 png files in the directory of the script. I can't find if the renderImage function can deal with more than one image. Also, I found that renderImage does not search in the script directory, but in another directory of temporary files. How can I fix this?

Here is the related code:

```
    observe({
    if (input$startkegg != 0) { # referecne to an actionButton "Start"
      
      kegg <- reactive({ enrichKEGG(entrezIDs() ,pAdjustMethod="fdr", pvalueCutoff=input$keggp, qvalueCutoff=input$keggq)}) # Some bioinformatics stuff
      
      output$enrichKegg <- renderImage({
        width  <- session$clientData$output_enrichKegg_width
        height <- session$clientData$output_enrichKegg_height
        outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
        
        png(outfile)
        pathview(gene.data=entrezIDs(), pathway.id=as.matrix(summary(kegg())[1])[1:3],species = "hsa", limit=3) # The function which generates a image with the output of the previous instruction.
        dev.off()
        
        list(src = outfile,
             width = width,
             height = height,
             alt = "plotGoGraph")
      }, deleteFile = FALSE)
    }
  })
```

I almost managed to resolve the problem in a "dirty" way, but using tag$img and renderUI, but for that I have to move the images in a 'www' subfile, and my 'system' command did not work:

```
observe({
    if (input$startkegg != 0) {
  
        kegg <- reactive({ enrichKEGG(entrezIDs(), pAdjustMethod=input$adjmk, pvalueCutoff=input$keggp, qvalueCutoff=input$keggq)})
        pathview(gene.data=entrezIDs(), pathway.id=as.matrix(summary(kegg())[1])[1:3],species = "hsa", limit=3)
        system("copy hsa04060.pathview.png www")
        system("copy hsa04064.pathview.png www")
        system("copy hsa04668.pathview.png www")
        #Essayer de mettre la commande pathview dans un tempoutfile : un temp par pathview
        
        output$pathway1 <- renderUI({ tags$img(src="hsa04060.pathview.png", width="400px", height="247px") })
        output$pathway2 <- renderUI({ tags$img(src="hsa04064.pathview.png", width="400px", height="318px") })
        output$pathway3 <- renderUI({ tags$img(src="hsa04668.pathview.png", width="400px", height="273px") })
        
    }
})
```

Comment: `?shiny::addResourcePath` my help solving your issue : Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42008543/how-to-print-file-to-shiny-using-rendertext/42010409#42010409

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but I still got an empty output :/. I used - addResourcePath("hsa", ".") : the images names all start by "hsa", and the '.' is to work in the current directory (the one with the shiny script). Could it be because the images have to be in a subfolder ? Which command R could do that ? I cannot move manually the images, everything has to be done under shiny

Comment: Not being able to reproduce your issue, I can't really help further. Please post a minimal reproducible working example to increase your chance of receiving an answer.